# change the array value in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have written a code for calculate maximum of a function with Genetic Algorithm in Python. this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458954/maximum-of-a-function-with-the-genetic-algorithm-in-python#_=_).

When I want to change the value of an array, I get an error:

```
def _crossover_chromosomes(chromosome1,chromosome2):
   crossover_chrom = Chromosome()
   for i in range(8):
     if random.random() >= 0.5:
        crossover_chrom.get_genes()[0][i] = chromosome1.get_genes()[0][i]
        crossover_chrom.get_genes()[1][i] = chromosome1.get_genes()[0][i]
     else:
        crossover_chrom.get_genes()[0][i] = chromosome2.get_genes()[0][i]
        crossover_chrom.get_genes()[1][i] = chromosome2.get_genes()[0][i]
return crossover_chrom
```

in this part, 'for' run only once and When it wants to change the array value in the fifth line, exits the program.

error:

```
    crossover_chrom.get_genes()[0][i] = chromosome1.get_genes()[0][i]
    TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Dont you think that "I get an error" is far less helpfull for helping you with your problem  than actually put the error message in your questions?

Comment: sorry, I edited the code

Comment: what does `get_genes()` return specifically? Is it a `numpy` array or any other data type?

Comment: It looks like your 'array' is a list of strings.  For this kind of editing it needs to be a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but looking at what you provided seems like

```
crossover_chrom.get_genes()[0]
```

returns a string. So you you are trying to assign a new value to a string by index, hence the error.
If assigning to a string is what you want (aka change a single character of the string at i-th position) you can do it like this:

```
crossover_chrom.get_genes()[0] = "{0}{1}{2}".format(
    crossover_chrom.get_genes()[0][:i],
    chromosome1.get_genes()[0][i],
    crossover_chrom.get_genes()[0][i+1:])
```

or better by assigning separately the values to a temporary variable for clarity and to avoid calling the get_gene function every time:

```
orig_gene=crossover_chrom.get_genes()[0]
new_gene1=chromosome1.get_genes()[0]
#...
orig_gene = "{0}{1}{2}".format(
        orig_gene[:i],
        new_gene1[i],
        orig_gene[i+1:])
```

Else you have to convert the string to a list (can do it by simply calling list on the object eg:

```
list(crossover_chrom.get_genes()[0])
```

or by modifying get_genes() to return a list of lists instead of instead of a list of strings.

Comment: It was perfectly correct! Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Python strings are immutable. You can't have for example `a='10010110'` and assign `a[3]='1'`. It is what causes the error. You need to avoid strings. Use array of `bool` or array of `integers` instead.

Something like:

```
class Chromosome:
  def __init__(self):
    self._genes = [[],[]]
    self._fitness = 0
    self.xd = 0
    self.yd = 0

    xd = random.randint(0,256)
    self._genes[0] = [ int(xd/2**i%2) for i in reversed(range(8))]

    yd = random.randint(0,256)
    self._genes[1] = [ int(yd/2**i%2) for i in reversed(range(8))]
```

Comment: I changed the code but I get this error: self._genes[0] = [ int(xd/2**i%2) for i in reversed(range(8))]
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Me stupid, Tuples are immutable the same way as strings :-). It must be a list. I fixed it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

A way to get around the string immutability in python is to rebuild the string.
This is an example to change a character to upercase at a certain index:

```
index=3
string="abcdefgh"

string= string[:index]+string[index].upper()+ string[index+1:]
print(string)
```

This will print out:

```
abcDefgh
```